# Python - Generate a list of IP addresses from user input

Tags: python

I am trying to create a script that generates a list of IP addresses based on a users input for a start and end IP range.  For example, they could enter 192.168.1.25 & 192.168.1.50.  The list would then be fed into scapy to test for open ports.  I think I have the list generated, but I am stuck on getting the individual IP's out and into the rest of my code. I think I am trying to use the whole list vs. an item in the list.  If there is a better way of doing this, that is fine.  I am doing this mainly to improve my understanding of Python.

Thanks!

```
from scapy.all import *

ip_start = raw_input('Please provide the starting IP address for your scan --> ')
start_list = ip_start.split(".")
ip_end = raw_input('Please provide the ending IP address for your scan --> ')
end_list = ip_end.split(".")
top = int(start_list[3])
bot = int(end_list[3])
octet_range = range(top,bot)
#print octet_range
for i in octet_range:
    #new_ip_start = ip_start.replace(str(top),str(i))

    start_list[3] = i
    #print top
    #print i
    print type(start_list)    
    src_port = RandShort()
    dst_port = 80
    scan = sr1(IP(dst=str(start_list))/TCP(sport=src_port,dport=dst_port,flags="S"),timeout=10)
```

Comment: Your not up to something good are you?

Comment: I am taking a class on python for pentesting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It'd be easier to use a format like `nmap`'s:

```
192.168.1.1-255
```

As now, you can do:

```
octets = '192.168.1.1-255'.split('.')
parsed_ranges = [map(int, octet.split('-')) for octet in octets]
```

`parsed_ranges` will look like `[[192], [168], [1], [1, 255]]`. From there, generating the addresses is simple with `itertools`:

```
import itertools

ranges = [range(r[0], r[1] + 1) if len(r) == 2 else r for r in parsed_ranges]
addresses = itertools.product(*ranges)
```

Here's a simple implementation:

```
import itertools

def ip_range(input_string):
    octets = input_string.split('.')
    chunks = [map(int, octet.split('-')) for octet in octets]
    ranges = [range(c[0], c[1] + 1) if len(c) == 2 else c for c in chunks]

    for address in itertools.product(*ranges):
        yield '.'.join(map(str, address))
```

And the result:

```
>>> for address in ip_range('192.168.1-2.1-12'):  print(address)
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.5
192.168.1.6
192.168.1.7
192.168.1.8
192.168.1.9
192.168.1.10
192.168.1.11
192.168.1.12
192.168.2.1
192.168.2.2
192.168.2.3
192.168.2.4
192.168.2.5
192.168.2.6
192.168.2.7
192.168.2.8
192.168.2.9
192.168.2.10
192.168.2.11
192.168.2.12
```

Comment: Let me try and wrap my head around this.  Your solution is much cleaner, I just need get a better understanding of some of the functions and new module.

Comment: I tried using your fuction with the parameter I gathered using raw_input.  range = raw_input('Enter range'), for i in ip_range(range): print i

Comment: The error I am getting is: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: For Python 3: wrap `map` around a `list`. (in Python 3, map returns an iterable object of type map, and not a subscriptable list)

Answer (score 5):

Remember that a dotted IPv4-address "x.x.x.x" is nothing more than a human-readable representation of a 32-bit integer. Using this, you can generate the ranges like this:

```
def undotIPv4 (dotted):
    return sum (int (octet) << ( (3 - i) << 3) for i, octet in enumerate (dotted.split ('.') ) )

def dotIPv4 (addr):
    return '.'.join (str (addr >> off & 0xff) for off in (24, 16, 8, 0) )

def rangeIPv4 (start, stop):
    for addr in range (undotIPv4 (start), undotIPv4 (stop) ):
        yield dotIPv4 (addr)

for x in rangeIPv4 ('1.2.3.4', '1.2.4.22'):
    print (x)
```

Comment: +1 for a more elegant solution. You could also use `struct.unpack` with `socket.inet_aton` and `socket.inet_ntoa`.

Comment: @Blender Those would be the more "native" approach without doubt, but I think it would hide a bit the simple maths that's behind it, and would thus obfuscate the logic. For production use, I would go with your option, for the sake of explaining my approach, I would stick to the "manual" way of dotting and undotting.